# Proper garbage collect for bullets

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm using a simple bullet system for a game I am working on but I was wondering whats the best way to remove the bullets from the array and screen so its not taking up frame rate and memory?

```
-(void)spinTapped
{     
        [self.character stopAllActions];
        [self.character runAction:self.gunAction];
        isRunning = NO;
        CCSprite *bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rwby_bullet.png"];
        bullet.position = ccp(self.character.position.x , self.character.position.y + 15);
        [bullet setScale:2];
        if (isRight) {
            bullet.tag = 10;
        }
        else {
            bullet.tag = -10;
        }
        [bullets addObject:bullet];
        [self addChild:bullet z:-1];

}
```

and then in the update:

```
for(CCSprite *bullet in bullets)
    {
        CGPoint bulletPosition = ccp(bullet.position.x , bullet.position.y);
        CGPoint B_tilePosition = [self tileCoorForPosition:bulletPosition];
        bullet.position = ccp(bullet.position.x + bullet.tag , bullet.position.y);

        NSMutableArray *emptySpace = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10000];
        [emptySpace addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

        @try {
            bullet_GID = [self.background tileGIDAt:B_tilePosition];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            bullet_GID = 535677655;
        }
        @finally {

        }
        if(bullet_GID == 535677655)
        {
            [bullet setVisible:NO];
          //  [bullets removeObject:bullet];

        }
        else if(bullet_GID)
        {
            [bullet setVisible:NO];
          //  [bullets removeObject:bullet];
        }
    }
```

The [bullets removeObject:bullet] causes the app to crash when one bullet hits a tile and another is on the screen (is what I assume the problem is). So what is the proper way of removing the bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the crash is probably because you are trying to remove your bullet object from the bullets array 'while iterating the array' : cant modify an array while iterating it. So, I suggest you do something like

```
NSMutableArray *bulletsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

for (CCSprite *bullet in bullets) {
   // your logic 
   if('should remove bullet') {
       [bulletsToRemove addObject:bullet];
   }
}

// now iterate the bullets to remove array, and remove safely from
// the bullets array

for (CCSprite *bulletToRemove in bulletsToRemove) {
    [bullets removeObject:bulletToRemove];
}
```

Comment: It's saying bullet is an undeclared identifier which makes sense because I'm not declaring it anywhere in the bulletsToRemove. Where should I declare it?

Comment: sorry, edited my answer ! in the second loop i had the wrong variable name.

Comment: You could also use [bullets removeObjectsInArray:bulletsToRemove];

Comment: That makes more sense! However it crashes as soon as it runs and highlights the bulletsToRemove for loop as the cause?

Comment: @AaronGolden ... true. i usually have other stuff to do to the bullet before flushing it, that is why i chose systematically the long form :)

Comment: Any reason for the crash?

Comment: If there is no bullets at the start would that cause the crash? In other words do I need a null check or should I add the [bulletsToRemove:bullet] to where I create the bullet?

Comment: that other crash would probably be another question. But you should only 'flag' an object in the toRemove array when it meets the criteria for removal.

Comment: Alright, just to make sure the bulletsToRemove loop is in the update correct?

Comment: it should be right after your initial loop ... in the same method as in the example. The scope of the bulletsToRemove array i showed is the method, ie not visible/accessible in other class code.

Comment: use [bullets reverseObjectEnumerator] then you're allowed to remove the enumerated object. That'll be faster too because removeObject: enumerates the array again until the to be removed object is found.